# How to exit a function with a return value without using "return" in c++

Tags: c++

How would I exit a function with a return value without using `return`.

Is there something like this in c++ :

```
auto random_function() {
    printf("Random string"); // Gets executed

    exit_with_return_value(/* Any random value. */);

    printf("Same string as before"); // Doesn't get executed
}
```

Because I'm aware about `exit()` which takes a exit code.
But is there any way I could exit with a return value.

It is just that I can't call `return` is parentheses like this:

```
( return /* random value*/ );
```

But I can call functions in parentheses,

```
(exit(0));
```

My use case:

```
 template <typename ...Parameters>
 class Parameter_Pack 
 {
 private:
     void* paramsAddr[sizeof...(Parameters)];

 public:
     Parameter_Pack(Parameters ...parameters) { 
        size_t count = 0;
       
       ((
        parameters, 
        this->paramsAddr[count] = malloc(sizeof(Parameters)), 
        *(Parameters*)paramsAddr[count] = parameters, 
        count++
      ), ...);
    }

    auto operator[](size_t index) {
        size_t count = 0;
        try {
           (((count == index ? : return * 
             (Parameters*)paramsAddr[index] : * 
             (Parameters*)paramsAddr[index]), count++), ...);
         } catch (Parameters...) {
              std::cout << "Error: " << std::endl;
         }
   }

    const size_t size() const {
        return sizeof...(Parameters);
    }
};
```

The problem is I can't return in `auto operator[](size_t index)`.

The compiler error is :

"expected primary-expression before 'return'"

Comment: you can throw an exception, but it is unclear what you actually want to achieve. Why do you want to exit without return?

Comment: Why would you want that ? What is wrong with `return` ?

Comment: `int main() {}` It will return `0`.  You're welcome!!  =)

Comment: no matter how you "exit" , the printf wont be executed after you exited the function. Please add some context.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to do this or is it just an academic question?

Comment: `std::exit` does not "exit a function". It causes the whole application to terminate

Comment: Throwing an exception is the only way I can think of.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy Any way I could catch without knowing the exception type?

Comment: Are you actually asking "can I return from a function as an expression?"

Comment: why would you want to write `( return /* random value*/ );` ? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you think you need to add `()` to the return statement?

Comment: Can you add an example situation in which you would like to call "return in parentheses"? Why don't you just call it without parentheses?

Comment: Ok I will post my entire use case.

Comment: good. Make sure its a [mcve] (in the current code it is unclear what `exit_with_return_value(/* Any random value. */);` is supposed to be or do)

Comment: Why not just unpack the parameter pack into a [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)? It makes your `Parameter_Pack` `class` unnecessary.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev Yeah, and you can, using `std::get`

Comment: @WBuck It seems that I cant put in a variable but have to manually enter a number as the template argument, because the compiler throws this error :              ***type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for*** `'template<class _Tp, class ... _Types> constexpr const _Tp&& std::get(const std::tuple<_UTypes ...>&&)'`

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(Parameters)), *(Parameters*)paramsAddr[count] = parameters` This is not going to work. What problem are you trying to solve with this class? I recommend asking about that problem.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It does work actually, Its just after creating array of `void*`, I need to be able to convert the element at the specified index at `auto operator[](size_t)` to index of the type in the `Parameters...`.

Comment: "It does work actually" Well for some small values of "work" perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` is a statement. Statements can't be part of a larger expression, so you can't `return` as a subexpression of some larger expression.

`throw` is an expression. It can be a subexpression of a larger expression, and you can `throw` any object you like.

It will be inconvenient for your callers, particularly if you mix it with an ordinary return. It will also not match the expectations other programmers have for how functions work. For that reason, I suggest you don't `throw` when you mean `return`.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out the data type of the exception being thrown?

Comment: If you're throwing, you should know the type, since you're throwing for a specific reason. Throwing is not a replacement for returning.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but instead of reinventing the wheel why not unpack the parameter pack into an `std::tuple`. You can then use `std::get` to access the `object`'s by index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename ...Args>
static void unpack(Args&& ...args) 
{
    std::tuple pack{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };

    int first = std::get<0>(pack);
    std::cout << first << '\n';

    const std::string& second = std::get<1>(pack);
    std::cout << second << '\n';

    bool third = std::get<2>(pack);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << third << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    unpack(42, std::string{ "Some string" }, false);
}
```

OK, so the only thing I could come up with that kind of does what you want is to use a `std::vector` in conjunction with a `std::variant`.

Personally I think this would be an annoying API to use but it will allow you to return multiple types from the subscript `operator` and doesn't require a constant expression, i.e. `index` can be a runtime value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename ...Args>
class Pack {    
public:
    using Types = std::variant<Args...>;

    Pack(Args... args)
        : pack_{ std::move(args)... }
    {}

    Types& operator[](const std::size_t index) {
        return pack_.at(index);
    }

    std::size_t size() const noexcept {
        return pack_.size();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Types> pack_;
};

int main() {
    Pack pack{42, std::string{ "Some string" }, false};
    std::cout << pack.size() << '\n';

    if (int* num = std::get_if<int>(&pack[0])) {
        std::cout << "My num: " << *num << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: The first template argument of `std::get` is a type and not a value. So I cannot pass an arithmetic variable i.e. a variable of type `int, long, ...etc` as a template parameter.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev "The first template argument of std::get is a type" [Not really](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get).

Comment: @AmritSanjeev ... However it must be a *constant expression*. And this is exactly the problem with your attempt. *Types in C++ do not depend on run-time values*. You cannot have a return type that changes depending on a regular function parameter. `auto` doesn't allow you to do that. You cannot declare `ParameterPack<int, double, std::vector<std::string>> pack` and have `pack[0]` returning an `int`, `pack[1]` returning a `double`, and `pack[2]` returning a `vector<string>`. (A `vector<string>` can't be placed there anyway because you can't `malloc` such a thing, but whatever makes you happy).